# database syncing in appengine

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I am using webapp2, python 2.7. 
Following is my model definition:

```
class Match(db.Model):
    date_time = db.DateTimeProperty()
    team1 = db.StringProperty()
    team2 = db.StringProperty()
    venue = db.StringProperty()
    result = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Now i write a custom file, to read a data/csv file and update the model by by making post request to views which catch them.  I update the localdatabase and can see the updated value at:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore
```

AFAIK to populate the data on the server, i need to run the same script with a change url to populate data on the server.

Is there any way i keep both the databases synced??
Push the current datastore from local to server and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this documentation: [Uploading and Downloading Data](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata)

This page will tell you all about uploading and downloading data. One key thing to remember, is that High Replication Datastore is not as consistent as the Master/Slave one, so if you attempt to download all data, you may not get the latest records (this is noted in the linked page). There also some functions that are available on the server, that are not available on the SDK, such as download all entities option.